# SUM IF with multiple conditions in the same collumn

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, array, conditional-statements

How to make this work in libre office Calc?

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Aug.N$2:N$400, {"ED","EDS","CS"},Aug.AD$2:AD$400))
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! You need to give a context when asking a question. For you , what you wrote might seem clear but it is not the case. What are you trying to achieve? Please edit your question and provide some context.

Comment: Maybe helpful, too: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers ...